# When @PersistenceContext are created?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use spring 4.3.1, hibernate 4.3.11.
I have an issue with hibernate lazy loading.
I have two examples
First works fine

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void lazy1() {
    List<WorkActivity> list = workActivityFacade.findAll();
    list.stream().forEach(wa -> wa.getWorkActivityTelephonyStatusMappings().size());
}
```

The second fails with org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: WorkActivity.workActivityTelephonyStatusMappings, could not initialize proxy - no Session

```
@Test
public void lazy2() {
    test();
}

@Transactional
public void test() {
    List<WorkActivity> list = workActivityFacade.findAll();
    list.stream().forEach(wa -> wa.getWorkActivityTelephonyStatusMappings().size());
}
```

My question is - why?
As I understand lazy load would work if you read and run lazy loading in the same session, or more general, in one persistence context.
WorkActivityFacade is ejb stateful bean that wraps entity manager with transaction persistence context. Why in first case transaction context is created on method's start and exists during method running, but in second case it created only in bean?

UPD1 - full code of my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringInstanceTestClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
public class WorkActivityFacadeTest {

@Autowired
private WorkActivityFacade workActivityFacade;

@Autowired
private TelephonyStatusFacade telephonyStatusFacade;

@Autowired
private WorkActivityTelephonyStatusMappingFacade mappingFacade;

Random r = new Random();

private static TelephonyStatus telephonyStatus;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    telephonyStatus = telephonyStatusFacade.create(new TelephonyStatus("test", Color.CYAN, "s" + r.nextDouble()));
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    //telephonyStatusFacade.remove(telephonyStatus);
}

protected WorkActivity initializeEntity() {
    WorkActivity wa = new WorkActivity(Color.CYAN, "test activity", true, false, false);
    //wa.setTelephonyStatusList(Collections.singletonList(telephonyStatus));
    return wa;
}

@Test
public void lazy() {
    WorkActivity created = workActivityFacade.create(initializeEntity());
    mappingFacade.create(new WorkActivityTelephonyStatusMapping(created, telephonyStatus));
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void lazy1() {
    List<WorkActivity> list = workActivityFacade.findAll();
    list.stream().forEach(wa -> wa.getWorkActivityTelephonyStatusMappings().size());
}

@Test
public void lazy2() {
    test();
}

@Transactional
public void test() {
    List<WorkActivity> list = workActivityFacade.findAll();
    list.stream().forEach(wa -> wa.getWorkActivityTelephonyStatusMappings().size());
}
```

}

Comment: Your `@Transactional` on the second one is useless. That method isn't transactional and as such it will fail. Only direct method invocations (and not internal ones) have the transactions applied. Your `lazy2` method isn't transactional and as such `test` isn't either.

Comment: Please post complete Test class. Is `@Transactional` at class level also ?

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean by "direct method invocation"? Can you advice something to read to understand where I should and where I shouldn't use `@Transactional`?

Comment: @VinayVeluri No, it is not. Check upd1 please.

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. Only method calls into the object pass through the proxy. As soon as you are inside the proxy and call a `@Transactional` method that will not work as it won't pass through the proxy. Although Test classes aren't proxies they  behave the same, only `@Test` methods can be `@Transactional` anything else (inside the test class) will be ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum it makes sense. Thank you a lot.